# Can I use Google Cloud Messaging for two step verification?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, user-registration

We are developing an app that requires the users to be connected to the internet either via WiFi or via 4G or 3G.

Can we use GCM, Google Cloud Messaging, to register and verify a user instead of SMS ?

That is, we are trying to find an alternative to text message or SMS, for sending a verification code to the user, similar to the way that apps like WhatsApp do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide 2 step authentication for users of your website, certainly GCM is a very good option. Create table that links GCM ids to user ids. YOu will of course need to write a bit of code to handle GCM registration id changes.

If you want to provide 2 step authentication for users of your android app. GCM certainly isn't a good option. Why because the 2 step authentication should involve a different device.

You can also try Google Authenticator app. No need for SMS when you use it.